# Converting an entire directory from UTF-8 to Shift JIS in Windows

Tags: file-converter, unicode, japanese, encoding, subtitles

I need to be able to convert an entire directory of txt-like files (.srt files in this case) from UTF-8 to Shift JIS. I'm looking for efficient ways to do this, since its likely I'll need to do this semi-frequently (for context/reason, Greenfish Subtitle Player supports Shift JIS but not Unicode for its subtitle player).

Currently, the most efficient solution I have found is to use gedit, and manually save each file as a new file with Shift JIS as the encoding, and then repeating for every file in the directory, but this is slow and time consuming.

Whatever the solution is, it will need to work on Windows (without having to set up a Linux subsystem/shell).

Comment: Looking into the code of Greenfish Subtitle Player, looks like it reads the subtitles with `new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.Default, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true);`. So maybe you can keep the files are UTF-8, but add a BOM (Byte Order Mark) to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this quickly in Python 3, (available completely *free* from [www.python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) or the Windows Store), it is a fast and simple install.

```
import sys
import pathlib

def convert_dir(indir: pathlib.Path, outdir: pathlib.Path):
    """ Convert all of the .srt files in the indir to Shift JIS in outdir. """
    if not outdir.exists():
        outdir.mkdir(parents=True)
    for n, infile in enumerate(indir.glob("*.srt", recurse=False)):
        print(f"Processing {infile.name}")
        outfile = outdir / infile.name
        outfile.write_bytes(infile.read_bytes().decode("utf-8").encode("shift-jis"))
        # Note shift_jis_2004 or shift_jisx0213 may work better than shift_jis
    return n

if len(sys.argv) == 3: # Check that we have the required number of parameters
    indir = pathlib.Path(sys.argv[1])
    outdir = pathlib.Path(sys.argv[2])
    print(f"{convert_dir(indir, outdir)} files written to {outdir}")
else:
    print("Usage: convert_dir input_dir output_dir")
```

You can test to see if this will work with input_dir and output_dir the same in your case, *I think that it may **if** all of the files are small enough to be read into RAM*.

*Thanks to @benrg for pointing out errors in original code.*

Comment: @benrg Thanks, I have corrected the code to what was intended - _I blame the late hour for the original_.

Comment: I like the "files smaller than RAM" disclaimer - either I am missing something, or it is deeply anachronistic :D

Comment: @VladimirCravero - As a person who spends a lot of time in the embedded world I tend to be highly aware of resource limitations - some of the targets that I deal with have storage available in the tens of kBs. My untested theory is that if the read is complete before the write starts overwriting the file should not be a problem. Of course I don't have any `.srt` files to test with. :-) Of course it could just be a reflection on my age.

Comment: A reflection of your *experience* - there, fixed it ;) Back to the topic at hand, I would expect python to be able to work with streams and occupy little memory for this task, as decoding & encoding only require sequential access. Perhaps there are lazy implementations of decode & encode, but chaining the calls like you suggest is going to load the full file. Mostly a moot discussion, but still, an interesting one. Cheers!